# Adding raster values when plotting a whole raster stack

Tags: r, raster

How can I add raster values while plotting the whole raster stack using `text()`? it can be managed easily while plotting a single raster but I am puzzled how I can do it for a whole raster stack.

example data:

```
set.seed(123)
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.3)
rr <- lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r1,seq(1,ncell(r1),1)))
s <- stack(rr)
```

for a single raster it is as below:

```
plot(s[[1]])
text(s[[1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the graphical parameter `par` and loop through the layers for plotting instead of using `plot` on the entire stack:

```
set.seed(123)
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.3)
rr <- lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r1,seq(1,ncell(r1),1)))
s <- stack(rr)

# 3 rows, 4 columns
par(mfrow=c(3,4))

for (ii in 1:nlayers(s)){

  plot(s[[ii]])
  text(s[[ii]])

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Val. It works fine but this also is mixed up while zoomed.

Comment: @Majid mixed up in what way?

Comment: When you zoom the plot text moves away from the cell centre but only if zoomed! Other than that it works fine.

Comment: @Majid you mean inside the plot window? I'm assuming this is due to the way the image is layered. When exported as png, everything is in place.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with "terra"

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(res=1, xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, vals=1:9)
s <- rep(r, 4) * 1:4
plot(s, fun=function(i) text(s[[i]]))
```

---

Older example with "raster"

Example data

```
set.seed(123)
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.3)
rr <- lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r1, sample(ncell(r1))))
s <- stack(rr)
```

The simple approach

```
par(mfrow=c(3,4))
for (i in 1:nlayers(s)) {
    plot(s[[i]])
    text(s[[i]])
}
```

Fancier, but a but tricky. It uses a global variable `i` that you must reset to 1 each time before you use it with `plot`

```
f <- function() {  text(s[[i]]); i <<- i + 1 }
i <- 1
plot(s, addfun=f)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Is that a bug so that when you zoom the texted plot then the text is displaced?

Comment: There is displacement if you resize the plotting window. Yes that is a bug. Work-around: plot, resize, and then plot again.